# How to implement to 2 different function ie onblur and on key up on same input box in zend form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I am new in zend framework.

I have implemented onblur function in zend form and i also what to implement on keyup function on same same input box.
It is possible to call 2 functions on same input box.
If yes please tell me the syntax. This is my code in zend form:

```
$this->addElement('text', 'userid', array(

        'label'      => '',
        'required'   => true,
        'filters'    => array('StringTrim'),
        'style'    => array('width:212px'),
        'onBlur' => 'getsecurityQues(this.value);',
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid inline javascript as far as possible. Google progressive enhancement for more information. If you use the elements id ('userid' in this case) you can add the js using the jquery library based on the id hook.

Jquery js code will look something like this...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $('#userid').keyup(function() {
            //do keyup stuff

         }
     });

     $('#userid').blur(function() {
            //do blur stuff

         }
     });
});
```

add the js in your controller action like this.

```
$this->view->headScript()->appendFile('/path/to/js/file.js');
```